# An error in one vim plugin prevents another from autoloading?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

At one point a while ago, vim ceased to autoload the file type plugin that
I use for .tex files (I use latex-suite to type latex; hence the file type plugin was something like tex_latexSuite.vim)

The screenshot below is the error message that I used to receive, whenever vim would not autoload tex_latexSuite.vim

I tracked the error message to a different plugin (bookmarks.vim) and, when I deleted the plugin, found thereafter that tex_latexSuite.vim would load as it used to originally.

What would have caused an error in bookmarks.vim to prevent tex_latexSuite.vim from autoloading correctly?
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/vim-scripts/bookmarks.vim/blob/ba649d6cc238db8364339d11c39132f8b749a268/plugin/bookmarks.vim#L241

This part doesn't have endif

Comment: And I would say the limitation of Vim script. When exception occur, Vim script skip the following part in the line which is separated by |. So if exception occured in the part of token, Vim script miss the endif eventhough it exists. So you should not use `if xxx | call some_thing() | endif`